# Android - tranistion from unsigned to signed apk distribution

Tags: android, apk, digital-signature, apksigner

TL;DR: How to install signed apk over unsigned version?

I am developing an app, which has about 150 users. The app isn't on Google Play, I'm distributing it as an apk from my website.

It has implemented mechanism for checking for updates. When update is found, app shows dialog with button to download. On click the apk is downloaded to Downloads folder and intent to that file called.

I've learned a lot since I started developing that app, and now I'd like to use apk signing. But I can clearly imagine what a pain would it be to explain to 150 users steps to uninstall and install again that app in a small dialog window. Furthermore, their preferences would be lost (among others, saved username and password).

So, is there a way? If not, do you have any good advices?

How would it be least painful for users?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. They should manually install the new signed package and before/after that uninstall previous unsigned-version. If the packagename is the same they will be forced to uninstall th  unsigned one BEFORE the new installation.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support installation of unsigned APKs, so the APK you have distributed to your 150 users *must* be already signed. See [this article](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/) which explicitly says:

> Every application that is run on the Android platform must be signed by the developer.

You have thus two options:

- **Option 1:** Use that same key to publish to Google Play. Your users will keep receiving updates as long as you publish APKs with higher version codes.
- **Option 2:** Use a new key to publish to Google Play. Your users *will* have to uninstall, and there is unfortunately no way around it, since it's a basic security feature of the Android platform.